# Some clarification needed abous Boost asio asynchronous operations and timers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

There are one aspect of the timers in asynchronous connections I want to know if I understand correctly.

Suppose that we set a timer before performing a read operation, which includes a handler, and then, `run()` the io_service.

As I have understood, the io_service ends as soon as the manager ends after being invoked, which can happen for two reasons:

a) the read operation is complete.

b) the timer has reached its limit.

Suppose that the first (a) condition has been reached, and the read operation has been completed before the timer ends.

The question is: What happens to that timer? Do we need to finish it. Say

```
dTimer_.expires_from_now (boost::posix_time::seconds(0));

after the io_service.run()?
```

Can you reset it to a new interval if necessary re-use the same timer object for another read operation?

Can I reset() the io_service and reuse the same object in a new `run()` for that new operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The question is: What happens to that
>   timer? Do we need to finish it.

The timer's handler will still be invoked if you do not [cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html) it

```
void my_read_handler() {
     dTimer_.cancel(); // remember to catch exceptions
}
```

The `async_wait handler` will be passed an [error code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html) of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` if it was successfully canceled. If the `async_wait` completed before the `cancel` and the handler had already been queued by the `io_service`, your handler will need to detect that condition and react appropriately.

---

> Can you reset it to a new interval if
>   necessary re-use the same timer object
>   for another read operation?

A deadline_timer can be [reset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now/overload2.html) using `expires_from_now`

> This function sets the expiry time.
>   Any pending asynchronous wait
>   operations will be cancelled. The
>   handler for each cancelled operation
>   will be invoked with the
>   boost::asio::error::operation_aborted
>   error code.

---

> Can I reset() the io_service and reuse
>   the same object in a new run() for
>   that new operation?

The same `io_service` object can be used again to `run()` or `poll()` after [resetting](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) it.

> This function must be called prior to
>   any second or later set of invocations
>   of the run(), run_one(), poll() or
>   poll_one() functions when a previous
>   invocation of these functions returned
>   due to the io_service being stopped or
>   running out of work. This function
>   allows the io_service to reset any
>   internal state, such as a "stopped"
>   flag.

Comment: Comprehensive answer, + 1 for boost::asio::error::operation_aborted

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and crisp explanation of the process involved, but still a question: supposing my first scenario, if there is a read operation and a timer, does the io_service ends when the first is ended? the former? or both?

Comment: @Old newbie `io_service::run()` returns control to the caller when there's no more work to do, this is well described in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html). In your context it means all the outstanding handlers, both `async_read` and `async_wait`, will be invoked before it returns.